# Eliminating duplicated elements in a list

Tags: python, list

I was trying chp 10.15 in book Think Python and wrote following codes:

```
def turn_str_to_list(string):
    res = []
    for letter in string:
        res.append(letter)
    return res

def sort_and_unique (t):
    t.sort()
    for i in range (0, len(t)-2, 1):
        for j in range (i+1, len(t)-1, 1):
            if t[i]==t[j]:
                del t[j]
    return t

line=raw_input('>>>')
t=turn_str_to_list(line)
print t
print sort_and_unique(t)
```

I used a double 'for' structure to eliminate any duplicated elements in a sorted list.
However, when I　ran it, I kept getting wrong outputs.
if I input 'committee', the output is ['c', 'e', 'i', 'm', 'o', 't', 't'], which is wrong because it still contains double 't'.
I tried different inputs, sometimes the program can't pick up duplicated letters in middle of the list, and it always can not pick up the ones at the end.
What was I missing? Thanks guys.

Comment: Really appreciated your answers guys. I know there is 'set()' that can eliminate duplicated elements. However I still wanted to know why my code is not working.

Comment: I added new answer explaining what is happening with your code

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The reason why your program isn't removing all the duplicate letters is because the use of `del t[j]` in the nested for-loops is causing the program to skip letters.

I added some prints to help illustrate this:

```
def sort_and_unique (t):
    t.sort()
    for i in range (0, len(t)-2, 1):
        print "i: %d" % i
        print t
        for j in range (i+1, len(t)-1, 1):
            print "\t%d %s len(t):%d" % (j, t[j], len(t))
            if t[i]==t[j]:
                print "\tdeleting %c" % t[j]
                del t[j]
    return t
```

Output:

```
>>>committee
['c', 'o', 'm', 'm', 'i', 't', 't', 'e', 'e']
i: 0
['c', 'e', 'e', 'i', 'm', 'm', 'o', 't', 't']
        1 e len(t):9
        2 e len(t):9
        3 i len(t):9
        4 m len(t):9
        5 m len(t):9
        6 o len(t):9
        7 t len(t):9
i: 1
['c', 'e', 'e', 'i', 'm', 'm', 'o', 't', 't']
        2 e len(t):9
        deleting e
        3 m len(t):8
        4 m len(t):8
        5 o len(t):8
        6 t len(t):8
        7 t len(t):8
i: 2
['c', 'e', 'i', 'm', 'm', 'o', 't', 't']
        3 m len(t):8
        4 m len(t):8
        5 o len(t):8
        6 t len(t):8
i: 3
['c', 'e', 'i', 'm', 'm', 'o', 't', 't']
        4 m len(t):8
        deleting m
        5 t len(t):7
        6 t len(t):7
i: 4
['c', 'e', 'i', 'm', 'o', 't', 't']
        5 t len(t):7
i: 5
['c', 'e', 'i', 'm', 'o', 't', 't']
i: 6
['c', 'e', 'i', 'm', 'o', 't', 't']
['c', 'e', 'i', 'm', 'o', 't', 't']
```

Whenever `del t[j]` is called, the list becomes one element smaller but the inner j variable for-loops keeps iterating.

For example:

`i=1, j=2, t = ['c', 'e', 'e', 'i', 'm', 'm', 'o', 't', 't']`

It sees that t[1] == t[2] (both 'e') so it removes t[2].

Now `t = ['c', 'e', 'i', 'm', 'm', 'o', 't', 't']`

However, the code continues with `i=1`, `j=3`, which compares 'e' to 'm' and skips over 'i'.

Lastly, it is not catching the last two `'t'`s because by the time `i=5`, `len(t)` is 7, so the conditions of the inner for-loop is `range(6,6,1)` and is not executed.

Comment: Great answer. Now I understand why it skips some of the letters. I can understand that when `del t[j]` delete a element from the list, the list immediately become shorter, however it surprise me that the `len(t)` also changed real time.

Comment: @homerMeng The `len(t)` tells you correct value each time you ask for it. For both loops it is at the moment they start. The outer loop starts just once. The inner loop start many times and in later case might find the list shorter then before, so it returns smaller length.

Answer (score 2):

In python you could make use of the inbuilt data structures and library functions like `set()` & `list()`

Your `turn_str_to_list()` can be done with `list()`. Maybe you know this but wanted to do it on your own.

Using the list() and [set()](https://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/datastructures.html#sets) APIs:

```
line=raw_input('>>>')
print list(set(line))
```

Your `sort_and_unique()` has a O(n^2) complexity. One of the ways to make cleaner:

```
def sort_and_unique2(t):
    t.sort()
    res = []
    for i in t:
        if i not in res:
            res.append(i)

    return res
```

This would still be O(n^2) since look up (i not in res) would be linear time, but code looks a bit cleaner. Deletion has complexity O(n), so instead you could do append to new list since append is O(1). See this for complexities of list API: https://wiki.python.org/moin/TimeComplexity

Comment: Thanks RBK. Yes I do know the built in function list() and set(), but since the book doesn't cover set() in that chp so I assume the intention of the exercise it to write a function your self. Your sort_and_unique2() is cool, there is always fun to see a piece of beautiful code. However, I still can't understand why my code doesn't work despite it is O(n^2) complexity.

Comment: @homerMeng, what I think is happening is that when `i = 5`, `j = i + 1 = 6`. `len(t)-1 = 6` (since e, m removed, len(t) = 9-2 = 7). And the range for j loop becomes `range(6,6)` which means the loop doesn't run and leaves the last character untouched.

Comment: thanks again for your reply, now I understand what is happening.

Answer (score 1):

Here you go:

```
In [1]: word = 'committee'

In [3]: word_ = set(word)

In [4]: word_
Out[4]: {'c', 'e', 'i', 'm', 'o', 't'}
```

The standard way to check for unique elements in python is to use a set. The constructor of a set [takes any sequential object](http://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/Python_Programming/Sets#Constructing_Sets). A string is a collection of sequential ascii codes (or unicode codepoints), so it qualifies.

If you have further problems, do leave a comment.

Comment: Using list comprehensions just for the loop (rather than for the values that go into the list) is a bad idea. Use `set(word)` or `world_ = set(); word_.update(word)` instead. Note though that this code will not preserve the order of the non-duplicated elements of the list. If you need that, another approach is necessary.

Comment: Why is `Using list comprehensions just for the loop (rather than for the values that go into the list)` a bad idea?

Comment: Two reasons. First of all, [explicit is better than implicit](http://legacy.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0020/). If you want a loop, write a loop. If you want to a list, then use a list comprehension. Secondly, it wastes memory. Your list comprehension builds a list full of `None` values (see `Out[6]`) that then throws the list away. For a small list that's probably not too costly, but if you deal with large amounts of data (especially if you get near the limits of your available RAM), you'll notice the time spent allocating and deallocating the memory!

Comment: @Blckknght how about now?

Comment: Thanks. But I still need to know what's wrong with my code. I understand set() can do the job, just for learning the language, I want to know what's happening in my codes.

Answer (score 1):

## Solution explained:

```
>>> word = "committee"
```

Turn string to list of characters:

```
>>> clst = list(word)
>>> clst
['c', 'o', 'm', 'm', 'i', 't', 't', 'e', 'e']
```

Use `set` to get only unique items:

```
>>> unq_clst = set(clst)
>>> unq_clst
{'c', 'e', 'i', 'm', 'o', 't'}
```

It turns out (thanks Blckknght), that the `list` step is not necessary and we could do that this way:

```
>>> unq_clst = set(word)
{'c', 'e', 'i', 'm', 'o', 't'}
```

Both, `set` and `list` are taking as parameter an iterable, and iterating over string returns one character by another.

Sort it:

```
>>> sorted(unq_clst)
['c', 'e', 'i', 'm', 'o', 't']
```

## One line version:

```
>>> sorted(set("COMMITTEE"))
['C', 'E', 'I', 'M', 'O', 'T']
```

Comment: There's no need to convert the string to a list if you're going to wrap it in `set` immediately afterwards.

Comment: @Blckknght This is what I like on SO - learning something new every day. I will modify it using your one step simpler trick. Thanks.

Comment: Converting "COMMITTEE" to a list is superfluous, `set("COMMITTEE")` works fine because strings are iterables.

Comment: Thanks. But I still want to know what's wrong with my code, any idea?

Answer (score 1):

You can try the following code snippet

```
s = "committe"
res = sorted((set(list(s))))
```

Comment: You should never need `set(list(s))` -- `set(s)` will always have the same result without making a temporary list.

Answer (score 0):

So you want to have explained, what is wrong in your code. Here you are:

## Before we dive into coding, make test case(s)

It would make our coding faster, if we get test case at hand from very begining

For testing I will make small utility function:

```
def textinout(text):
    return "".join(sort_and_unique(list(text)))
```

This allows quick test like:

```
>>> textinout("committee")
"ceimot"
```

and another helper function for readable error traces:

```
def checkit(textin, expected):
    msg = "For input '{textin}' we expect '{expected}', got '{result}'"
    result = textinout(textin)
    assert result == expected, msg.format(textin=textin, expected=expected, result=result)
```

And make the test case function:

```
def testit():
    checkit("abcd", 'abcd')
    checkit("aabbccdd", 'abcd')
    checkit("a", 'a')
    checkit("ddccbbaa", 'abcd')
    checkit("ddcbaa", 'abcd')
    checkit("committee", 'ceimot')
```

Let us make first test with existing function:

```
def sort_and_unique (t):
    t.sort()
    for i in range (0, len(t)-2, 1):
        for j in range (i+1, len(t)-1, 1):
            if t[i]==t[j]:
                del t[j]
    return t
```

Now we can test it:

```
testit()
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
AssertionError                            Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-11-291a15d81032> in <module>()
----> 1 testit()

<ipython-input-4-d8ad9abb3338> in testit()
      1 def testit():
      2         checkit("abcd", 'abcd')
----> 3         checkit("aabbccdd", 'abcd')
      4         checkit("a", 'a')
      5         checkit("ddccbbaa", 'abcd')

<ipython-input-10-620ac3b14f51> in checkit(textin, expected)
      2     msg = "For input '{textin}' we expect '{expected}', got '{result}'"
      3     result = textinout(textin)
----> 4     assert result == expected, msg.format(textin=textin, expected=expected, result=result)

AssertionError: For input 'aabbccdd' we expect 'abcd', got 'abcdd'
```

Reading the last line of error trace we know, what is wrong.

## General comments to your code

### Accessing list members via index

In most cases this is not efficient and it makes the code hard to read.

Instead of:

```
lst = ["a", "b", "c"]
for i in range(len(lst)):
    itm = lst[i]
    # do something with the itm
```

You should use:

```
lst = ["a", "b", "c"]
for itm in lst:
    # do something with the itm
    print itm
```

If you need to access subset of a list, use slicing

Instead of:

```
for i in range (0, len(lst)-2, 1):
    itm = lst[i]
```

Use:

```
for itm in lst[:-2]:
    # do something with the itm
    print itm
```

If you really need to know position of processed item for inner loops, use enumerate:

Instead of:

```
lst = ["a", "b", "c", "d", "e"]
for i in range(0, len(lst)):
    for j in range (i+1, len(lst)-1, 1):
        itm_i = lst[i]
        itm_j = lst[j]
        # do something
```

Use enumerate, which turn each list item into tuple (index, item):

```
lst = ["a", "b", "c", "d", "e"]
for i, itm_i in enumerate(lst):
    for itm_j in lst[i+1, -1]
        print itm_i, itm_j
        # do something
```

## Manipulating a list which is processed

You are looping over a list and suddenly delete an item from it. List modification during iteration is generally better to avoid, if you have to do it, you have to
think twice and take care, like iterating backward so that you do not modify that part, which is
about to be processed in some next iteration.

As alternative to deleting an item from iterated list you can note findings (like duplicated items) to another list and
after you are out of the loop, use it somehow.

## How could be your code rewritten

```
def sort_and_unique (lst):
    lst.sort()
    to_remove = []
    for i, itm_i in enumerate(lst[:-2]):
        for j, itm_j in enumerate(lst[i+1: -1]):
            if itm_i == itm_j:
                to_remove.append(itm_j)
    # now we are out of loop and can modify the lst
    # note, we loop over one list and modify another, this is safe
    for itm in to_remove:
        lst.remove(itm)
    return lst
```

Reading the code, **the problem turns out: you never touch last item in the sorted list.** That is why you do not get `"t"` removed as it is alphabetically the last item after applying sort.

So your code could be corrected this way:

```
def sort_and_unique (lst):
    lst.sort()
    to_remove = []
    for i, itm_i in enumerate(lst[:-1]):
        for j, itm_j in enumerate(lst[i+1:]):
            if itm_i == itm_j:
                to_remove.append(itm_j)
    for itm in to_remove:
        lst.remove(itm)
    return lst
```

From now on, the code is correct, and you shall prove it by calling `testit()`

```
>>> testit()
```

Silent test output is what we were dreaming about.

Having the test function make further code modification easy, as it will be quick to check, if things are still working as expected.

Anyway, the code can be shortened by getting tuples `(itm_i, itm_j)` using `zip`

```
def sort_and_unique (lst):
    lst.sort()
    to_remove = []
    for itm_i, itm_j in zip(lst[:-1], lst[1:]):
        if itm_i == itm_j:
            to_remove.append(itm_j)
    for itm in to_remove:
        lst.remove(itm)
    return lst
```

Test it:

```
>>> testit()
```

or using list comprehension:

```
def sort_and_unique (lst):
    lst.sort()
    to_remove = [itm_j for itm_i, itm_j in zip(lst[:-1], lst[1:]) if itm_i == itm_j]
    for itm in to_remove:
        lst.remove(itm)
    return lst
```

Test it:

```
>>> testit()
```

As list comprehension (using `[]`) completes creation of returned value sooner then are the values
used, we can remove another line:

```
def sort_and_unique (lst):
    lst.sort()
    for itm in [itm_j for itm_i, itm_j in zip(lst[:-1], lst[1:]) if itm_i == itm_j]:
        lst.remove(itm)
    return lst
```

Test it:

```
>>> testit()
```

Note, that so far, the code still reflects your original algorithm, only two bugs were removed:

```
- not manipulating list, we are iterating over
- taking into account also last item from the list
```

Comment: Wow, thanks for your reply Jan. It was quite a lot information and habit for me to digest. I like the way the keep the duplicated letters in another list during the loop and use it out of the loop.

Comment: @homerMeng Sorry, I take things sometime a bit wider then is usual. But you picked up the core message for your task.